# Solving a two-sample z-test for two population proportions is to be performed using the P-value approach.

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

The null hypothesis is $H_0:P_1=P_2$ and the alternative is $H_a:P_1\neq P_2$. Use the given sample data to find the P-value for the hypothesis test. Give an interpretation of the p-value.

$n_1=200$
 
$n_2=100$
 
$x_1=11$
 
$x_2=8$

I got a p-value of $0.4009$ but I'm not sure how to interpret this p-value and what it means or if my result is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no difference in the proportions, there is about a 40.1% chance of seeing the observed difference or larger by natural sampling variation

I think this is the right interpretation for the p-value.

By the way, R u in UA? Stat151 in M.Yaskina's class.

Comment: Small world. Yea I am.